# AngularDart Transformation/Deployments

Tags: dart, angular-dart, dart-pub, dart2js, dart-shelf

I am building a client/server app in Dart using Angular for the front-end and Shelf on the backend. When I do a `pub build` it generates the javascript for the Dart files as expected but is does not replace the dart references in my HTML files. So in my index.html I have the following script reference:

```
<script type="application/dart" src="main.dart"></script>
```

This makes my application not load correctly. If I manually change it to

```
<script src="main.dart.js"></script>
```

My application works as expected. My question is, is there a way to configure my pub build to do this automatically? Or are dart files references not supposed to be replaced with JS references? If so, how do I build a basic server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know this produces an error message in the browser console but never experienced any problems because of this.

I haven't used it myself yet but I think this transformer https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/dart_to_js_script_rewriter does what you want.